# How to handle a function call in JavaScript without modifying the function

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

I'm trying to catch and handle a function call to make something when the function is being called,
but I can't modify the function itself because I'm writing an UserJS so I would like to work with the function provided to me.

So all I need is to create a kind of "event handler" but for a function call.

Example:

```
TestSample.sync = function (arg1, arg2, arg3){
        //some function things
}
```

So I need a handler to let me do some stuff every time when the function is being called.

How to do it using JS?

Comment: As you've written it, I don't see a way to do that directly. If you know what event is causing the function to fire, you can try adding a handler on that same event. If you know what other thing (some calling function) might be invoking the function you cannot change, then you could change that calling function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by overwriting the function with binded context and adding my code into it (i think it`s not a good practice but it worked for my case)

```
var __fakeFunc = window.TestSample.sync.bind(window.TestSample); 

// Overwrite the original function, adding extra actions.
        TestSample.sync = function (arg1, arg2, arg3)  {
        // Add any code you need
        // Call the original function using it's temporary variable.
        __fakeFunc(arg1, arg2, arg3);
    }
```